# couldn't sum the values of the variables in loop in python. what is the way to fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is my first quation and i am learning python still. i want to input the values of the variables and variables will be like x1, x2, x3 ... and then i want to sum all the variables value in a loop so that i can get the mean. i don't want to use mean() function as i am trying to make something by my own.

here is my code:

```
n=input("how many samples do you want to put:")
n=int(n)
for i in range (1,n+1):
 p="x"+str(i)+":"
 vol=int(input(p))
 vol+=vol
 print(vol)
```

the problem is that first variable is adding up with itself and i know that this is just because of vol=+vol but i can't have any other way to sume the next variable input value with previous. i tried the same thing with the dictionary thing but end up nowhere:

```
import sys
n=input("how many samples do you want to put:")
n=int(n)
for i in range (1,n+1):
p="x"+str(i)+":"
vol=int(input(p))
s={p: vol}
print(s.values())
```

please give me any idea how to solve it.

how many samples do you want to put:3
x1:22
22
x2:33
22
x3:44
22
sum=66

Comment: Use another variale for the sum? or add it directly to a sum?
 `vol_sum += int(input(f"x{i}:"))` ?

Comment: It would be benefficial to learn some basics from a tutorial - f.e. here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice to hear that your want to build things on your own. As others have pointed out, you are reassigning the vol-variable and overwriting your total. Here is an example of how I would do it:

```
n = int(input("Have many samples do you want to put: "))
tot = 0

for i in range(n):
    tot += int(input(f"x{i+1}: "))

print(f"Total of samples = {tot}")
```

Answer (score 3):

add 
vol=0
before the for statement. and change the variable name of the input.

```
n=input("how many samples do you want to put:")
n=int(n)
vol = 0
for i in range (1,n+1): 
    p="x"+str(i)+":" 
    v=int(input(p)) 
    vol+=v
print(vol)
```

Comment: thanks, your answer helped me. actually my goal is to make something for standard deviation and linear regression without using built in functions of python.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are reassigning vol every time in the loop to the inputted value.
Instead of reassigning it just add the inputted value to it.

```
n=input("how many samples do you want to put:")
n=int(n)
for i in range (1,n+1):
    p="x"+str(i)+":"
    vol+=int(input(p))
    print(vol)
```